# Does wpa_passphrase use a hashing algorithm?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless, wpa

The question is pretty clear. I'm wondering if it uses a hashing algorithm, or it is simply an encryption. If it is a hash, then what algorithm is used (md5, sha1, etc)? Also, does the router compare the password in plain text for validation or a hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPA-PSK, the WPA passphrase and SSID are used to derive the 256 AES key used to encrypt the wireless traffic. The key derivation function is PBKDF2, defined in [RFC 2898](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt). If the passphrase for the SSID is correct the encryption will work so that the client can successfully communicate with the AP. Otherwise, the communication will fail. That's how the AP knows the passphrase is correct (the traffic isn't gibberish).

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand correctly, the router will decrypt the 256-bit encrypted value and then compare?

Comment: The traffic between the client and AP is AES 256 encrypted and the passphrase check is implicit. If the client has the correct key (which was derived from the passphrase and SSID) for the AP the handshaking will work because both ends will be able to decrypt the traffic correctly. There isn't an explicit comparison of the passphrase by the AP.